# How to avoid xmlns="" in an XML-element added?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

I have 287 SSRS reports (XML files), where I need to add a parameter.
They all start like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
<DataSources>
<DataSource Name="COR_Basic">
<rd:DataSourceID>addde073-f37c-4b59-ae3a-25231ffc0ec6</rd:DataSourceID>
<DataSourceReference>COR_Basic</DataSourceReference>
</DataSource>
</DataSources>
<InteractiveHeight>29.7cm</InteractiveHeight>
<ReportParameters>
<ReportParameter Name="in_report_name">
<DataType>String</DataType>
<DefaultValue>
<Values>
<Value>=Globals!ReportName</Value>
</Values>
</DefaultValue>
<Prompt>Report Name</Prompt>
<Hidden>true</Hidden>
</ReportParameter>
<ReportParameter Name="in_mandant">
<DataType>String</DataType>
<DefaultValue>
<Values>
<Value>0</Value>
</Values>
</DefaultValue>
<Prompt>in_mandant</Prompt>
<Hidden>true</Hidden>
</ReportParameter>
```

Now I want to automagically add the "proc" parameter to all reports. 
Which means I need to insert this bit of XML

```
<ReportParameter Name="proc">
<DataType>String</DataType>
<DefaultValue>
<Values>
<Value>MyTestValue</Value>
</Values>
</DefaultValue>
<Prompt>MyPromptText</Prompt>
<Hidden>true</Hidden>
</ReportParameter>
```

after

```
<ReportParameter Name="in_mandant">
...
</ReportParameter>
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
public static System.Xml.XmlDocument File2XmlDocument(string strFileName)
{
    // http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tolong/archive/2007/11/15/read-write-xml-in-memory-stream.aspx
    System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    // doc.Load(memorystream);
    // doc.Load(FILE_NAME);

    using (System.Xml.XmlTextReader xtrReader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(strFileName))
    {

        doc.Load(xtrReader);
        xtrReader.Close();
    } // End Using xtrReader

    return doc;
} // End Function File2XmlDocument




        public static System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager GetReportNamespaceManager(System.Xml.XmlDocument doc)
        {
            System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("dft", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition");

            return nsmgr;
        } // End Function GetReportNamespaceManager



 public static void AddProc(string strFilename)
        {
            System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = File2XmlDocument(strFilename);
            System.Xml.XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = GetReportNamespaceManager(doc);

            System.Xml.XmlNode xnMandant = root.SelectSingleNode("/dft:Report/dft:ReportParameters/dft:ReportParameter[@Name=\"in_mandant\"]", nsmgr);

            string strReportName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFilename);

            if (xnMandant != null)
            {
                LogMessage("{0}\t{1}", strReportName, xnMandant.FirstChild.Value);

                string frag = @"<ReportParameter Name=""proc"">
<DataType>String</DataType>
<DefaultValue>
<Values>
<Value>MyTestValue</Value>
</Values>
</DefaultValue>
<Prompt>MyPromptText</Prompt>
<Hidden>true</Hidden>
</ReportParameter>";

                System.Xml.XmlDocumentFragment xmlDocFrag = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
                xmlDocFrag.InnerXml = frag;

                System.Xml.XmlNode xn = xnMandant.ParentNode.InsertAfter(xmlDocFrag, xnMandant);

                Console.WriteLine(xn.OuterXml);

            }
            else
                LogMessage("{0}\tKein Parameter in_mandant", strReportName);


            SaveDocument(doc, strFilename);
        } // End Sub PrintStichtag
```

This inserts the XML-Fragment at the right location, but I have a `xmlns=""` after `"proc"`.

```
<ReportParameter Name="proc" xmlns="">
<DataType>String</DataType>
<DefaultValue>
<Values>
<Value>MyTestValue</Value>
</Values>
</DefaultValue>
<Prompt>MyPromptText</Prompt>
<Hidden>true</Hidden>
</ReportParameter>
```

How can I avoid the empty xmlns attribute ?
(Short of loading the xml file as text and doing string.replace) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this isn't possible at all ("thanks" to read-only property).
The only way around it is doing a replace on the OuterXml of the document, and reloading the document.

```
    public static void SaveDocument(System.Xml.XmlDocument doc, string strFilename, bool bDoReplace)
    {
        string strSavePath = GetSavePath();
        strSavePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(strSavePath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFilename));

        if (bDoReplace)
        {
            doc.LoadXml(doc.OuterXml.Replace("xmlns=\"\"", ""));
            // doc.LoadXml(doc.OuterXml.Replace(strTextToReplace, strReplacementText));
        }

        using (System.Xml.XmlTextWriter xtw = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(strSavePath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            xtw.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented; // if you want it indented
            xtw.Indentation = 4;
            xtw.IndentChar = ' ';

            doc.Save(xtw);
        } // End Using xtw

    } // End Sub SaveDocument
```

Comment: This should use the new XmlWriter instead. Enjoy this unformatted mess :) 
var xmlConfig = new XmlWriterSettings(){Indent = true, IndentChars = " ", Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8};
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(strSavePath, xmlConfig)){ doc.Save(xw); }

Answer (score 3):

> How can I avoid the empty xmlns attribute ?

Create the elements in the right namespace. Due to [namespace defaulting](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting), *all* your elements should be in the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition` namespace.

You could try inserting the fragment and *then* set its `InnerXml` value - it's possible that that will apply namespace defaulting appropriately.

Personally, however, I'd use LINQ to XML which makes namespace handling much, much simpler - and then construct the elements programmatically instead of parsing them from text. In fact, I'd construct the elements programmatically anyway rather than setting the `InnerXml` - it will make it easier to control precisely things like namespaces, as you can specify them when you construct the elements.

(I'd also strongly advise the use of `using` directives, to avoid your code being peppered with fully qualified names everywhere.)

Comment: @Quandary: Rats, hadn't spotted that. In that case, you could *try* adding it before setting the `InnerXml` fragment, but to be honest you'd be better off creating it programmatically.

Comment: That doesn't work either. But thanks anyway. I can't use LINQ btw, we're still on .NET 2.0...

Answer (score 0):

While adding use this namespace with following settings.

```
     XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
     namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
```